# Calendar won't open

Tags: php, javascript

I have this code:

```
    <link href="http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.worldservice.ua/shared/con1//bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('#ar').datepicker();
            $('#de').datepicker();
        });
    </script>
<div class="datepicker dropdown-menu"><div class="datepicker-days" style="display: block; "><table class=" table-condensed"><thead><tr><th class="prev">‹</th><th colspan="5" class="switch">February 2012</th><th class="next">›</th></tr><tr><th class="dow">Su</th><th class="dow">Mo</th><th class="dow">Tu</th><th class="dow">We</th><th class="dow">Th</th><th class="dow">Fr</th><th class="dow">Sa</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td class="day old">29</td><td class="day old">30</td><td class="day old">31</td><td class="day">1</td><td class="day">2</td><td class="day">3</td><td class="day">4</td></tr><tr><td class="day">5</td><td class="day">6</td><td class="day">7</td><td class="day">8</td><td class="day">9</td><td class="day">10</td><td class="day">11</td></tr><tr><td class="day">12</td><td class="day">13</td><td class="day">14</td><td class="day">15</td><td class="day active">16</td><td class="day">17</td><td class="day">18</td></tr><tr><td class="day">19</td><td class="day">20</td><td class="day">21</td><td class="day">22</td><td class="day">23</td><td class="day">24</td><td class="day">25</td></tr><tr><td class="day">26</td><td class="day">27</td><td class="day">28</td><td class="day">29</td><td class="day new">1</td><td class="day new">2</td><td class="day new">3</td></tr><tr><td class="day new">4</td><td class="day new">5</td><td class="day new">6</td><td class="day new">7</td><td class="day new">8</td><td class="day new">9</td><td class="day new">10</td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="datepicker-months" style="display: none; "><table class="table-condensed"><thead><tr><th class="prev">‹</th><th colspan="5" class="switch">2012</th><th class="next">›</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td colspan="7"><span class="month">Jan</span><span class="month active">Feb</span><span class="month">Mar</span><span class="month">Apr</span><span class="month">May</span><span class="month">Jun</span><span class="month">Jul</span><span class="month">Aug</span><span class="month">Sep</span><span class="month">Oct</span><span class="month">Nov</span><span class="month">Dec</span></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="datepicker-years" style="display: none; "><table class="table-condensed"><thead><tr><th class="prev">‹</th><th colspan="5" class="switch">2010-2019</th><th class="next">›</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td colspan="7"><span class="year old">2009</span><span class="year">2010</span><span class="year">2011</span><span class="year active">2012</span><span class="year">2013</span><span class="year">2014</span><span class="year">2015</span><span class="year">2016</span><span class="year">2017</span><span class="year">2018</span><span class="year">2019</span><span class="year old">2020</span></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div><div class="datepicker dropdown-menu"><div class="datepicker-days" style="display: block; "><table class=" table-condensed"><thead><tr><th class="prev">‹</th><th colspan="5" class="switch">February 2012</th><th class="next">›</th></tr><tr><th class="dow">Su</th><th class="dow">Mo</th><th class="dow">Tu</th><th class="dow">We</th><th class="dow">Th</th><th class="dow">Fr</th><th class="dow">Sa</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td class="day old">29</td><td class="day old">30</td><td class="day old">31</td><td class="day">1</td><td class="day">2</td><td class="day">3</td><td class="day">4</td></tr><tr><td class="day">5</td><td class="day">6</td><td class="day">7</td><td class="day">8</td><td class="day">9</td><td class="day">10</td><td class="day">11</td></tr><tr><td class="day">12</td><td class="day">13</td><td class="day">14</td><td class="day">15</td><td class="day active">16</td><td class="day">17</td><td class="day">18</td></tr><tr><td class="day">19</td><td class="day">20</td><td class="day">21</td><td class="day">22</td><td class="day">23</td><td class="day">24</td><td class="day">25</td></tr><tr><td class="day">26</td><td class="day">27</td><td class="day">28</td><td class="day">29</td><td class="day new">1</td><td class="day new">2</td><td class="day new">3</td></tr><tr><td class="day new">4</td><td class="day new">5</td><td class="day new">6</td><td class="day new">7</td><td class="day new">8</td><td class="day new">9</td><td class="day new">10</td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="datepicker-months" style="display: none; "><table class="table-condensed"><thead><tr><th class="prev">‹</th><th colspan="5" class="switch">2012</th><th class="next">›</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td colspan="7"><span class="month">Jan</span><span class="month active">Feb</span><span class="month">Mar</span><span class="month">Apr</span><span class="month">May</span><span class="month">Jun</span><span class="month">Jul</span><span class="month">Aug</span><span class="month">Sep</span><span class="month">Oct</span><span class="month">Nov</span><span class="month">Dec</span></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="datepicker-years" style="display: none; "><table class="table-condensed"><thead><tr><th class="prev">‹</th><th colspan="5" class="switch">2010-2019</th><th class="next">›</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td colspan="7"><span class="year old">2009</span><span class="year">2010</span><span class="year">2011</span><span class="year active">2012</span><span class="year">2013</span><span class="year">2014</span><span class="year">2015</span><span class="year">2016</span><span class="year">2017</span><span class="year">2018</span><span class="year">2019</span><span class="year old">2020</span></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div><div class="datepicker dropdown-menu"><div class="datepicker-days" style="display: block; "><table class=" table-condensed"><thead><tr><th class="prev">‹</th><th colspan="5" class="switch">February 2012</th><th class="next">›</th></tr><tr><th class="dow">Su</th><th class="dow">Mo</th><th class="dow">Tu</th><th class="dow">We</th><th class="dow">Th</th><th class="dow">Fr</th><th class="dow">Sa</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td class="day old">29</td><td class="day old">30</td><td class="day old">31</td><td class="day">1</td><td class="day">2</td><td class="day">3</td><td class="day">4</td></tr><tr><td class="day">5</td><td class="day">6</td><td class="day">7</td><td class="day">8</td><td class="day">9</td><td class="day">10</td><td class="day">11</td></tr><tr><td class="day active">12</td><td class="day">13</td><td class="day">14</td><td class="day">15</td><td class="day">16</td><td class="day">17</td><td class="day">18</td></tr><tr><td class="day">19</td><td class="day">20</td><td class="day">21</td><td class="day">22</td><td class="day">23</td><td class="day">24</td><td class="day">25</td></tr><tr><td class="day">26</td><td class="day">27</td><td class="day">28</td><td class="day">29</td><td class="day new">1</td><td class="day new">2</td><td class="day new">3</td></tr><tr><td class="day new">4</td><td class="day new">5</td><td class="day new">6</td><td class="day new">7</td><td class="day new">8</td><td class="day new">9</td><td class="day new">10</td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="datepicker-months" style="display: none; "><table class="table-condensed"><thead><tr><th class="prev">‹</th><th colspan="5" class="switch">2012</th><th class="next">›</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td colspan="7"><span class="month">Jan</span><span class="month active">Feb</span><span class="month">Mar</span><span class="month">Apr</span><span class="month">May</span><span class="month">Jun</span><span class="month">Jul</span><span class="month">Aug</span><span class="month">Sep</span><span class="month">Oct</span><span class="month">Nov</span><span class="month">Dec</span></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="datepicker-years" style="display: none; "><table class="table-condensed"><thead><tr><th class="prev">‹</th><th colspan="5" class="switch">2010-2019</th><th class="next">›</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td colspan="7"><span class="year old">2009</span><span class="year">2010</span><span class="year">2011</span><span class="year active">2012</span><span class="year">2013</span><span class="year">2014</span><span class="year">2015</span><span class="year">2016</span><span class="year">2017</span><span class="year">2018</span><span class="year">2019</span><span class="year old">2020</span></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div><div class="datepicker dropdown-menu"><div class="datepicker-days" style="display: none; "><table class=" table-condensed"><thead><tr><th class="prev">‹</th><th colspan="5" class="switch">February 2012</th><th class="next">›</th></tr><tr><th class="dow">Su</th><th class="dow">Mo</th><th class="dow">Tu</th><th class="dow">We</th><th class="dow">Th</th><th class="dow">Fr</th><th class="dow">Sa</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td class="day old">29</td><td class="day old">30</td><td class="day old">31</td><td class="day">1</td><td class="day">2</td><td class="day">3</td><td class="day">4</td></tr><tr><td class="day">5</td><td class="day">6</td><td class="day">7</td><td class="day">8</td><td class="day">9</td><td class="day">10</td><td class="day">11</td></tr><tr><td class="day active">12</td><td class="day">13</td><td class="day">14</td><td class="day">15</td><td class="day">16</td><td class="day">17</td><td class="day">18</td></tr><tr><td class="day">19</td><td class="day">20</td><td class="day">21</td><td class="day">22</td><td class="day">23</td><td class="day">24</td><td class="day">25</td></tr><tr><td class="day">26</td><td class="day">27</td><td class="day">28</td><td class="day">29</td><td class="day new">1</td><td class="day new">2</td><td class="day new">3</td></tr><tr><td class="day new">4</td><td class="day new">5</td><td class="day new">6</td><td class="day new">7</td><td class="day new">8</td><td class="day new">9</td><td class="day new">10</td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="datepicker-months" style="display: none; "><table class="table-condensed"><thead><tr><th class="prev">‹</th><th colspan="5" class="switch">2012</th><th class="next">›</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td colspan="7"><span class="month">Jan</span><span class="month active">Feb</span><span class="month">Mar</span><span class="month">Apr</span><span class="month">May</span><span class="month">Jun</span><span class="month">Jul</span><span class="month">Aug</span><span class="month">Sep</span><span class="month">Oct</span><span class="month">Nov</span><span class="month">Dec</span></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="datepicker-years" style="display: block; "><table class="table-condensed"><thead><tr><th class="prev">‹</th><th colspan="5" class="switch">2010-2019</th><th class="next">›</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td colspan="7"><span class="year old">2009</span><span class="year">2010</span><span class="year">2011</span><span class="year active">2012</span><span class="year">2013</span><span class="year">2014</span><span class="year">2015</span><span class="year">2016</span><span class="year">2017</span><span class="year">2018</span><span class="year">2019</span><span class="year old">2020</span></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div><div class="datepicker dropdown-menu"><div class="datepicker-days" style="display: none; "><table class=" table-condensed"><thead><tr><th class="prev">‹</th><th colspan="5" class="switch">June 2012</th><th class="next">›</th></tr><tr><th class="dow">Su</th><th class="dow">Mo</th><th class="dow">Tu</th><th class="dow">We</th><th class="dow">Th</th><th class="dow">Fr</th><th class="dow">Sa</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td class="day old">27</td><td class="day old">28</td><td class="day old">29</td><td class="day old">30</td><td class="day old">31</td><td class="day active">1</td><td class="day">2</td></tr><tr><td class="day">3</td><td class="day">4</td><td class="day">5</td><td class="day">6</td><td class="day">7</td><td class="day">8</td><td class="day">9</td></tr><tr><td class="day">10</td><td class="day">11</td><td class="day">12</td><td class="day">13</td><td class="day">14</td><td class="day">15</td><td class="day">16</td></tr><tr><td class="day">17</td><td class="day">18</td><td class="day">19</td><td class="day">20</td><td class="day">21</td><td class="day">22</td><td class="day">23</td></tr><tr><td class="day">24</td><td class="day">25</td><td class="day">26</td><td class="day">27</td><td class="day">28</td><td class="day">29</td><td class="day">30</td></tr><tr><td class="day new">1</td><td class="day new">2</td><td class="day new">3</td><td class="day new">4</td><td class="day new">5</td><td class="day new">6</td><td class="day new">7</td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="datepicker-months" style="display: none; "><table class="table-condensed"><thead><tr><th class="prev">‹</th><th colspan="5" class="switch">2012</th><th class="next">›</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td colspan="7"><span class="month">Jan</span><span class="month">Feb</span><span class="month">Mar</span><span class="month">Apr</span><span class="month">May</span><span class="month active">Jun</span><span class="month">Jul</span><span class="month">Aug</span><span class="month">Sep</span><span class="month">Oct</span><span class="month">Nov</span><span class="month">Dec</span></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="datepicker-years" style="display: block; "><table class="table-condensed"><thead><tr><th class="prev">‹</th><th colspan="5" class="switch">2010-2019</th><th class="next">›</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td colspan="7"><span class="year old">2009</span><span class="year">2010</span><span class="year">2011</span><span class="year active">2012</span><span class="year">2013</span><span class="year">2014</span><span class="year">2015</span><span class="year">2016</span><span class="year">2017</span><span class="year">2018</span><span class="year">2019</span><span class="year old">2020</span></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div><div class="datepicker dropdown-menu"><div class="datepicker-days" style="display: block; "><table class=" table-condensed"><thead><tr><th class="prev">‹</th><th colspan="5" class="switch">February 2012</th><th class="next">›</th></tr><tr><th class="dow">Su</th><th class="dow">Mo</th><th class="dow">Tu</th><th class="dow">We</th><th class="dow">Th</th><th class="dow">Fr</th><th class="dow">Sa</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td class="day old">29</td><td class="day old">30</td><td class="day old">31</td><td class="day">1</td><td class="day">2</td><td class="day">3</td><td class="day">4</td></tr><tr><td class="day">5</td><td class="day">6</td><td class="day">7</td><td class="day">8</td><td class="day">9</td><td class="day">10</td><td class="day">11</td></tr><tr><td class="day">12</td><td class="day">13</td><td class="day">14</td><td class="day">15</td><td class="day">16</td><td class="day">17</td><td class="day">18</td></tr><tr><td class="day">19</td><td class="day active">20</td><td class="day">21</td><td class="day">22</td><td class="day">23</td><td class="day">24</td><td class="day">25</td></tr><tr><td class="day">26</td><td class="day">27</td><td class="day">28</td><td class="day">29</td><td class="day new">1</td><td class="day new">2</td><td class="day new">3</td></tr><tr><td class="day new">4</td><td class="day new">5</td><td class="day new">6</td><td class="day new">7</td><td class="day new">8</td><td class="day new">9</td><td class="day new">10</td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="datepicker-months" style="display: none; "><table class="table-condensed"><thead><tr><th class="prev">‹</th><th colspan="5" class="switch">2012</th><th class="next">›</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td colspan="7"><span class="month">Jan</span><span class="month active">Feb</span><span class="month">Mar</span><span class="month">Apr</span><span class="month">May</span><span class="month">Jun</span><span class="month">Jul</span><span class="month">Aug</span><span class="month">Sep</span><span class="month">Oct</span><span class="month">Nov</span><span class="month">Dec</span></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="datepicker-years" style="display: none; "><table class="table-condensed"><thead><tr><th class="prev">‹</th><th colspan="5" class="switch">2010-2019</th><th class="next">›</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td colspan="7"><span class="year old">2009</span><span class="year">2010</span><span class="year">2011</span><span class="year active">2012</span><span class="year">2013</span><span class="year">2014</span><span class="year">2015</span><span class="year">2016</span><span class="year">2017</span><span class="year">2018</span><span class="year">2019</span><span class="year old">2020</span></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div><div class="datepicker dropdown-menu"><div class="datepicker-days" style="display: block; "><table class=" table-condensed"><thead><tr><th class="prev">‹</th><th colspan="5" class="switch">February 2012</th><th class="next">›</th></tr><tr><th class="dow">Su</th><th class="dow">Mo</th><th class="dow">Tu</th><th class="dow">We</th><th class="dow">Th</th><th class="dow">Fr</th><th class="dow">Sa</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td class="day old">29</td><td class="day old">30</td><td class="day old">31</td><td class="day">1</td><td class="day">2</td><td class="day">3</td><td class="day">4</td></tr><tr><td class="day">5</td><td class="day">6</td><td class="day">7</td><td class="day">8</td><td class="day">9</td><td class="day">10</td><td class="day">11</td></tr><tr><td class="day">12</td><td class="day">13</td><td class="day">14</td><td class="day">15</td><td class="day">16</td><td class="day">17</td><td class="day">18</td></tr><tr><td class="day">19</td><td class="day">20</td><td class="day">21</td><td class="day">22</td><td class="day">23</td><td class="day">24</td><td class="day active">25</td></tr><tr><td class="day">26</td><td class="day">27</td><td class="day">28</td><td class="day">29</td><td class="day new">1</td><td class="day new">2</td><td class="day new">3</td></tr><tr><td class="day new">4</td><td class="day new">5</td><td class="day new">6</td><td class="day new">7</td><td class="day new">8</td><td class="day new">9</td><td class="day new">10</td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="datepicker-months" style="display: none; "><table class="table-condensed"><thead><tr><th class="prev">‹</th><th colspan="5" class="switch">2012</th><th class="next">›</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td colspan="7"><span class="month">Jan</span><span class="month active">Feb</span><span class="month">Mar</span><span class="month">Apr</span><span class="month">May</span><span class="month">Jun</span><span class="month">Jul</span><span class="month">Aug</span><span class="month">Sep</span><span class="month">Oct</span><span class="month">Nov</span><span class="month">Dec</span></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="datepicker-years" style="display: none; "><table class="table-condensed"><thead><tr><th class="prev">‹</th><th colspan="5" class="switch">2010-2019</th><th class="next">›</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td colspan="7"><span class="year old">2009</span><span class="year">2010</span><span class="year">2011</span><span class="year active">2012</span><span class="year">2013</span><span class="year">2014</span><span class="year">2015</span><span class="year">2016</span><span class="year">2017</span><span class="year">2018</span><span class="year">2019</span><span class="year old">2020</span></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div>
 <script src="http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.worldservice.ua/shared/con1//bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('#ar').datepicker();
            $('#de').datepicker();
        });
    </script>
<?

/* Соединяемся с базой данных */
$hostname = "localhost"; // название/путь сервера, с MySQL
$username = "1"; // имя пользователя (в Denwer`е по умолчанию "root")
$password = "1"; // пароль пользователя (в Denwer`е по умолчанию пароль отсутствует, этот параметр можно оставить пустым)
$dbName = "1"; // название базы данных

/* Таблица MySQL, в которой хранятся данные */
$table = "confer_2";

if(isset($_POST['update'])){
    $update=$_POST['update'];
}
if(isset($_POST['fam1'])){
    $fam1=$_POST['fam1'];
}
if(isset($_POST['name1'])){
    $name1=$_POST['name1'];
}
if(isset($_POST['phone1'])){
    $phone1=$_POST['phone1'];
}
if(isset($_POST['email1'])){
    $email1=$_POST['email1'];
}
if(isset($_POST['job1'])){
    $job1=$_POST['job1'];
}
if(isset($_POST['state1'])){
    $state1=$_POST['state1'];
}
if(isset($_POST['city1'])){
    $city1=$_POST['city1'];
}
if(isset($_POST['addr1'])){
    $addr1=$_POST['addr1'];
}
if(isset($_POST['hotel1'])){
    $hotel1=$_POST['hotel1'];
}
if(isset($_POST['room1'])){
    $room1=$_POST['room1'];
}
if(isset($_POST['arr1'])){
    $arr1=$_POST['arr1'];
}
if(isset($_POST['dep1'])){
    $dep1=$_POST['dep1'];
}

/* Создаем соединение */
mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die ("Не могу создать соединение");
mysql_query("set collation_connection = 'cp1251_general_ci'");
mysql_query("set character_set_client='cp1251'");
mysql_query("set character_set_results='cp1251'");
mysql_query("set character_set_system='cp1251'");
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
/* Выбираем базу данных. Если произойдет ошибка - вывести ее */
mysql_select_db($dbName) or die (mysql_error());

/* Если была нажата кнопка редактирования, вносим изменения */
if(isset($_POST['submit_edit'])) {
$query = "UPDATE $table SET fam='$fam1', name='$name1', phone='$phone1', email='$email1', job='$job1', state='$state1', city='$city1', addr='$addr1', hotel='$hotel1', room='$room1', arr='$arr1', dep='$dep1' WHERE id='$update'";
/* Выполняем запрос. Если произойдет ошибка - вывести ее. */
mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
}


/* Заносим в переменную $res всю базу данных */
$query = "SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY fam";
/* Выполняем запрос. Если произойдет ошибка - вывести ее. */
$res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
/* Узнаем количество записей в базе данных */
$row = mysql_num_rows($res);

/* Выводим данные из таблицы */
echo ("

");

/* Цикл вывода данных из базы конкретных полей */
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    echo "<form action=\"?q=node/4\" method=\"post\" name=\"edit_form\">\n";
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"update\" value=\"".$row["id"]."\" />\n";
    echo "<table class=\"table table-striped\">\n";
    echo "<tr height=\"2\">\n";
    echo "<td><b>#".$row["id"]."  ".$row['data']."</b></td>\n";
    echo "</tr><tr>\n";
    echo "<td>Фамилия:</td><td><input type=\"text\" value=\"".$row['fam']."\" name=\"fam1\" /></td>\n";
    echo "<td>Имя/Отчество:</td><td><input type=\"text\" value=\"".$row['name']."\" name=\"name1\" /></td>\n";
    echo "<td>Телефон:</td><td><input type=\"text\" value=\"".$row['phone']."\" name=\"phone1\" /></td>\n";
    echo "<td>Email:</td><td><input type=\"text\" value=\"".$row['email']."\" name=\"email1\" /></td>\n";
    echo "</tr><tr>\n";
    echo "<td>Место работы:</td><td><input type=\"text\" value=\"".$row['job']."\" name=\"job1\" /></td>\n";

    echo "<td>Должность:</td><td><input type=\"text\" value=\"".$row['state']."\" name=\"state1\" /></td>\n";

    echo "<td>Город:</td><td><input type=\"text\" value=\"".$row['city']."\" name=\"city1\" /></td>\n";

    echo "<td>Адрес:</td><td><input type=\"text\" value=\"".$row['addr']."\" name=\"addr1\" /></td>\n";
   echo "</tr><tr>\n";
echo "<td>Отель:</td><td><input type=\"text\" value=\"".$row['hotel']."\" name=\"hotel1\" /></td>\n";
echo "<td>Номер:</td><td><input type=\"text\" value=\"".$row['room']."\" name=\"room1\" /></td>\n";
echo "<td>Заезд:</td><td><input type=\"text\" class=\"span2\" value=\"".$row['arr']."\" data-date-format=\"dd/mm/yy\" name=\"arr1\" id=\"ar\"></td>\n";
echo "<td>Выезд:</td><td><input type=\"text\" class=\"span2\" value=\"".$row['dep']."\" data-date-format=\"dd/mm/yy\" name=\"dep1\" id=\"de\"></td>\n";
    echo "</tr><tr>\n";
    echo "<td colspan=\"8\" colspan=\"8\" align=\"center\" class=\"table table-bordered\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit_edit\" class=\"btn btn-success\" value=\"Сохранить изменения\" /></td>\n";
    echo "</tr></table></form>\n\n";
}

/* Закрываем соединение */
mysql_close();

/* Выводим ссылку возврата */
/* echo ("<div style=\"text-align: center; margin-top: 10px;\"><a href=\"index.html\">Вернуться назад</a></div>"); */

?>
```

But the calendar opens only in first "block" of inputs. In the next "blocks", when I click on calendar input the javascript is not called. Where I need to do changes?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: do an f12 on your navigator and see console message (red number if exist on bottom right)

Comment: Why do you include jquery.js two times? and $(function()) also included two times...

Answer (score 3):

i think you have identical IDs, every returned row (in this case 106, 157) has same id (ar, de)

there are two options:

**a) when you call datepicker, use class selector**

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $('.date').datepicker();
});
</script>

<input type="text" class="date" />
```

**b) rename ids with row id**

where you have to specify each row id in script function
and make diferent input ids e.g.

```
echo '<input type="text" id="ar_'.$row['id'].'" />';
echo '<input type="text" id="de_'.$row['id'].'" />';
```

Comment: concat id name with $row["id"] for example